# Trying to call a stored procedure from mysql in python, keep getting a strange error column not found in fieldlist, any ideas?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run a simple stored procedure from python, but keep running into an error that persists no matter how I try to format according to faqs online.  When I call the stored procedure and enter the parameters directly in mysql it runs with the same error.  I am a mysql newb, so it could be something stupid I don't know.  Here is my stored procedure and it being tested in mysql, the table (whose contents are solely the admin admin being tested), the python code, and the error msg.

[stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlW4z.png)  [test in mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn4oO.png)  [python callproc code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz0m8.png)  [table referenced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj4Jf.png)  [python error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqjna.png)

Comment: You need to include the code here, so people can read it instantly. Furthermore, if it's included here as text, then it can be read by search-engine scrapers and by users with vision difficulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.  Changed the query slightly and needed quotations in the comparison parts for some reason.  Here is what it looks like now.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `userLogin`(
    in input_userId varchar(20),
    in input_password varchar(20),
    out loginMsg char(50))
begin
    set @numUsers = 0;
    select count(*) into @numUsers
    from login x
    where x.userId = input_userId and x.pword = input_password;
    if @numUsers = 1 then
        set loginMsg = "Login successful";
    else
        set loginMsg = "Invalid username/password";
    end if;
    end
```